# Android layout ordering for overlapping VideoViews not working correctly

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'am developing an app that will show 2 videos at the same time. One small in the bottom right corner and the other full screen (kinda).
When I run the video_view on an Android 6.0.1 device the order works correctly. But when i run it on a version newer (Android 7 for example) it does not order it correctly. Also the function setZ() does nothing for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <nl.hacker115.drivingwithdrivepro550.CustomVideoView
        android:id="@+id/roadCamera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <nl.hacker115.drivingwithdrivepro550.CustomVideoView
        android:id="@+id/faceCamera"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I want the faceCamera on top of the roadCamera, how can I do this?

My CustomVideoView.java looks like this

```
package nl.hacker115.drivingwithdrivepro550;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class CustomVideoView extends VideoView {
    private PlayPauseListener mListener;

    public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setPlayPauseListener(PlayPauseListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        super.pause();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPlay();
        }
    }

    public static interface PlayPauseListener {
        void onPlay();
        void onPause();
    }

}
```

Comment: First, all of the `app:layout_constraint*` attributes have no effect inside a `FrameLayout`, and you should delete those, so as not to cause any confusion. Second, base z-ordering generally goes by the order the `View`s are listed in the layout XML, with those listed later closer to the user, on the z-axis. If you mean for the smaller `CustomVideoView` in the bottom-end to be on top, with respect to z-order, then it should be listed last.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for helping so far, this is working fine on android 7 and higher but not on android 6.0.1 as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Did you try to faceCamera.bringToFront() or frameLayout.bringChildToFront(faceCamera) ?

Comment: Yeah, version isn't really relevant to my suggestion for your given layout. Generally speaking, if it's supposed to be on top of something, then it should be listed after that something.

Comment: @MikeM. I understand you're suggestion but that isn't working for me. I'm relatively new to android development. Any ideas how this can happen. On android 7 or higher it is showing correctly but on android 6 it isn't.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that you'd rearranged your layout, and were commenting about that. My bad. Distracted. Hmm, other than that, the only thing that comes to mind immediately, without having a chance to look at the source, is, does it possibly depend on which `CustomVideoView` starts playing first?

Comment: Since i'm new to the forum i have a question how can i upload the project?

Comment: Sorry, we're not a forum, in that sense. We're a Q&A site for specific, demonstrable problems. You'll have to whittle your project down to a [mcve] that you can include in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My knowledge in this area is very limited, but your issue is the following: The issue is because views like `VideoView` and `GLSurfaceView` need/provide a dedicated drawing area and are handled outside of the "normal" rendering pipeline that draws UI widgets. The image that they are showing is composited into the final image at a later stage. This stage has no knowledge about in what way the view is layout-ed.

I assume this was a bug or unspecified behavior in Android 6 in what order these views get composited onto the final image.

I was able to reproduce your issue and solved it by setting

```
faceCameraView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```

on the overlay `VideoView`.

For more information take a look at the class description of [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) which is the base class for `VideoView` and `GLSurfaceView`.

Comment: Thanks for you're solution this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This could be what you are looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<nl.hacker115.drivingwithdrivepro550.CustomVideoView
    android:id="@+id/roadCamera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<nl.hacker115.drivingwithdrivepro550.CustomVideoView
    android:id="@+id/faceCamera"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry I want the faceCam on top off the "full screen" road video. I'm trying to make a app that syncs both videos at the same time so that Driving students can see what they are doing when taking a turn for example. Syncing is working but the facecam is hidden behind the roadcam.

Comment: Yes and no it works on 8,0 for example but not on 6.0.1.

Comment: I tried more versions now and you're solution works for android 8.0 and up but i want it to atleast work from android 6.0.1 and up. I Just added the CustomVideoView.java to the question, maybe that clears something up? Thanks for so far!